# Copy data to another table before update or insert. Use stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I need to update in a database.  I am updating these tables from data in another database.  If a record in table 1 gets updated, I need the old information in table 1 to be stored in table 2.  I need logic in place to make a comparison and then update Table 2 if needed.  My question is, what is the best way to do this?  I am thinking a stored procedure would be the way to go, but I'm not sure.

Here is a more visual explanation.

```
    Table 1
Student    Grade
james       6
sarah       5



  Table 2
   EMPTY
```

Lets say that the data below is what I am pulling from another database.

```
   Other Database
  Student     Grade
   james        6
   sarah        4
   tom          7
```

Here is some sloppy logic that may help explain what I need to do.

```
--If records match do nothing 
IF otherDatabase.student =  table1.student  AND  otherDatabase.grade = table1.grade THEN do nothing

--If partial match copy old data to table 2 and insert new data to table1
IF otherDatabase.student = table1.student AND otherDatabse.grade !=  table1.grade 
THEN copy table1.student to table2.student AND copy table1.grade to table2.grade THEN UPDATE table1.grade from otherDatabase.grade

--If no match copy new data to Table1
IF otherDatabase.student != table1.student AND otherDatabase.grade != table1.grade THEN INSERT otherDatabase.student AND otherDatabase.grade INTO table1
```

In my example, James would not get touched, sarah would get moved to table 2 and then inserted into table 1 with new grade and tom would get inserted into table 1.

I am very sorry if this doesn't make sense.  Please allow me to clarify if needed. Thanks

Comment: You could do it in one table by adding a new column `previous_grade` to table 1. Would that be a suitable solution?

Comment: That is a good solution.  However, my example is just simple.  I really need to do compare about 8 fields.  Also, the Table1 is in a database that I'm not allowed to add or remove columns from. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a stored procedure, but I would use a trigger.

With a stored procedure, I'd perceive you using a cursor on the otherDatabase table to read through the records and compare each with the values in Table1 to determine whether Table1's data needed to be written to Table2, and if so, to do it.

With a trigger, I would simply update the data in Table1 by whatever means, without concerning myself with what the overwriting data is, and in the trigger,

use the old and new values using the ##Inserted & ##Deleted (system) tables to determine if the old values (##Deleted) needed to be written to Table2. Eg

```
INSERT Table2 (Student, Grade)
SELECT d.Student, d.Grade
FROM ##Deleted d LEFT JOIN ##Inserted i ON d.[Key] = i.[Key]
WHERE (d.Student <> i.Student OR d.Grade <> i.Grade) AND d.[Key] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Can I used the trigger method if there is more data in the table1 than what I cam bringing over from otherDatabase?  For example,  If it was school, name, grade, age, birthdate?  Even though I would only be comparing and updating name and grade?

Comment: Yes. Whenever you update a row in any table, both ##Inserted & ##Deleted are populated (with the new and old values of that row respectively), so if you only updated two columns, the values of the other columns in that row will be the same in both the ##Inserted & ##Deleted tables, but the updated columns would differ accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Drop procedure if exists getCID;
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE getCID(IN cid varchar(100))
BEGIN
    create table Temp as(select i.invoice_no,i.cust_id,b.tot_amount,b.paid_amount,b.bal_amount from invoice_item_info i,bill_info b where i.invoice_no=b.invoice_no and i.cust_id=cid);
select * from Temp;
select DISTINCT cust_id,count(invoice_no),sum(tot_amount),sum(paid_amount),sum(bal_amount) from Temp;
Drop table Temp;
END
//
delimiter ;
```